# If count equals number, append class

Tags: php

So I have the variable `$count` that will give me a count. What would be the best approach to append a class name to the `<div class="column">` section?

Here is sort of what I'm looking for:

- If count === 1, render `<div class="column">`
- If count === 2, render `<div class="column is-half">`
- If count === 3, render `<div class="column is-one-third">`
- If count === 4+, render `<div class="column is-one-quarter">`

Here is the code:

```
<?php $count = count($sub_items) ?>
<div class="column">
    <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title mb-2"><?= $sub_item->get_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php if ($sub_child_items = $sub_item->get_sub_items()): ?>
        <?php foreach ($sub_child_items as $sub_child_item): ?>
        <a class="navbar-item" href="<?= $sub_child_item->get_url(); ?>">
            <?= $sub_child_item->get_title(); ?>
        </a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: IMHO, As short tags (`<?= ?>`) can be disabled it is recommended to only use the normal tags (`<?php ?>`) to maximise compatibility.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman - Even with short tags disabled, the short hand echo `<?= ?>` will still be available.

Comment: Thanks @MagnusEriksson. But why is the full variant preferred than the short variant?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman - It's an old issue that's been mitigated. The short open tags setting use to include the short echo and since it was a setting, you couldn't count on it always being enabled. This is no longer the case since many PHP versions back, but you know how slowly old myths die, if ever. In general, there's nothing wrong with using the short echo syntax, and I haven't really heard much objections against it either.

Comment: Thanks! Learnt something new! @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do something like this using `switch` and please note the last case `default`:

```php
<?php
  $count = count($sub_items);
  $className = "column ";
  switch($count) {
    case 2:
      $className .= "is-half";
      break;
    case 3:
      $className .= "is-one-third";
      break;
    case 1:
    default:
      $className = ($count >= 4) ? "column is-one-quarter" : "column";
  }
?>
<div class="<?php echo $className; ?>">
    <h1 class="title is-6 is-mega-menu-title mb-2"><?= $sub_item->get_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php if ($sub_child_items = $sub_item->get_sub_items()): ?>
        <?php foreach ($sub_child_items as $sub_child_item): ?>
        <a class="navbar-item" href="<?= $sub_child_item->get_url(); ?>">
            <?= $sub_child_item->get_title(); ?>
        </a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Also, I would suggest to use `<?php echo $varName; ?>` instead of using `<?= $varName; ?>` for compatibility purposes.